# size of TLB entry

Tags: caching, tlb

**Problem**

What is the size of a TLB (translation lookaside buffer) entry in bits?

**Reference**

I use the definition/setup of a translation lookaside buffer from the book

*Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective* from Bryant et al.

The TLB entry consists of the TLB tag, the physical page number and a valid bit. Therefore, the size of a TLB entry equals bits required for TLB tag + bits required for a physical page number and 1 bit for the valid bit.

Is that correct?